# jQuery-keyfilter plugin

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-plugins, keyfilter

How would I use the keyfilter plugin and allow everything except < and >

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-keyfilter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it
`$('#field').keyfilter(/[^<^>]/);`